# Can you create crawl rules for file:// urls?

Tags: 2010, search, crawl-rules

In configuring our search service, we have set up a content source of \\server\projects. Within this source is a directory, \\server\projects\~backups. This backup directory contains hourly, daily, weekly and monthly snapshots of our project data. Our source contains over 500GB of legitimate project files (excluding ~backups, which pushes the total disk space into many terabytes of storage).

I want to ensure that the crawl excludes the ~backups directory. It seems I have two options:

- Create a source that enumerates all subdirectories of \\server\projects:

  - \\server\projects\projectA
  - \\server\projects\projectB (and so on)
- Create a source of file://server/projects and create a crawl rule to exclude file://server/projects/~backup.

However, reading [the documentation for crawl rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms562090%28v=office.12%29.aspx) says pretty explicitly that they are for http:// sources only. I'm not sure if I should read that in as "urls in general" as opposed  to LoB data, and Exchange Public Folder data, though. I'm a bit gunshy of starting another crawl with these rules because it will take many hours to complete the crawl.

Will the search service honor a file:// exclusion or will I need to use a list of subdirectories?

Comment: Why not just remove the crawl accounts permission on that folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can use the `\\server\site` UNC path and it should give you the option to allow subsites or directories..

See this link:
http://www.bfcnetworks.com/configure-sharepoint-2010-search-for-crawl-file-servers/

Likewise you can create crawl exclusions in the Crawl Rules...

Search Service Application -> Crawl Rules -> New -> *Type in the exclusion path*, Exclude all items in this path -> OK